# How can I do network type distribution in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

**Scenario**

Let’s say we have two types of entities, Compound Entities, and Isolated Entities. Both types of entities can be related in the following ways:

- Compound entities can be related to other Compound entities.
- Compound entities can be related to Isolated entities. (One way only)
- No relationships within Isolated entities are allowed.
- All relationships could be thought of like networks with different environments. This means that not all networks have to be connected.
- All Compound entities handle certain volume values.

**The Data**

The is stored in the following way:

*Relationship_Table*

```
╔══════════════╦════════════╦══════════════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║ Upper_Entity ║ Type_Upper ║ Lower_Entity ║ Type_Lower ║ Relation ║
╠══════════════╬════════════╬══════════════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║       201417 ║ Compound   ║       207654 ║ Compound   ║ 0.45     ║
║       103254 ║ Isolated   ║       201532 ║ Compound   ║ 1.00     ║
║       107892 ║ Isolated   ║       207654 ║ Compound   ║ 0.55     ║
║       107427 ║ Isolated   ║       201417 ║ Compound   ║ 1.00     ║
║       209876 ║ Compound   ║       205678 ║ Compound   ║ 0.15     ║
║       201645 ║ Compound   ║       205678 ║ Compound   ║ 0.35     ║
║       206453 ║ Compound   ║       205678 ║ Compound   ║ 0.5      ║
║       102847 ║ Isolated   ║       209876 ║ Compound   ║ 0.60     ║
║       103844 ║ Isolated   ║       209876 ║ Compound   ║ 0.40     ║
║       102847 ║ Isolated   ║       201645 ║ Compound   ║ 0.10     ║
║       102346 ║ Isolated   ║       201645 ║ Compound   ║ 0.90     ║
║       209846 ║ Compound   ║       206453 ║ Compound   ║ 0.38     ║
║       102973 ║ Isolated   ║       206453 ║ Compound   ║ 0.12     ║
║       109743 ║ Isolated   ║       206453 ║ Compound   ║ 0.50     ║
║       103254 ║ Isolated   ║       209846 ║ Compound   ║ 1.00     ║
╚══════════════╩════════════╩══════════════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

This table provides all the relationships that exist between entities

*Volume_Table*

```
╔════════╦═══════════╗
║ Entity ║  Volume   ║
╠════════╬═══════════╣
║ 207654 ║  733,369  ║
║ 201532 ║  752,115  ║
║ 201417 ║  170,370  ║
║ 205678 ║  764,799  ║
║ 209876 ║  975,799  ║
║ 201645 ║  237,336  ║
║ 206453 ║  825,702  ║
║ 209846 ║  332,103  ║
╚════════╩═══════════╝
```

This table provides the volume that handles every Compound Entity.

**What I want to do is:**

Distribute the volume of every Compound Entity based on the relation coefficients (provided in the first table), in such a way that at the end I have only Isolated Entities with the sum of all their corresponding volume.

What I can do right now is join the tables and multiply the respective relation coefficient with the volume:

```
╔══════════════╦════════════╦══════════════╦════════════╦══════════╦════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ Upper_Entity ║ Type_Upper ║ Lower_Entity ║ Type_Lower ║ Relation ║ Entity ║  Volume   ║ Level_1_Distribution ║
╠══════════════╬════════════╬══════════════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════╣
║       201417 ║ Compound   ║       207654 ║ Compound   ║ 0.45     ║ 207654 ║  733,369  ║  330,016.05          ║
║       103254 ║ Isolated   ║       201532 ║ Compound   ║ 1.00     ║ 201532 ║  752,115  ║  752,115.00          ║
║       107892 ║ Isolated   ║       207654 ║ Compound   ║ 0.55     ║ 207654 ║  733,369  ║  403,352.95          ║
║       107427 ║ Isolated   ║       201417 ║ Compound   ║ 1.00     ║ 201417 ║  170,370  ║  170,370.00          ║
║       209876 ║ Compound   ║       205678 ║ Compound   ║ 0.15     ║ 205678 ║  764,799  ║  114,719.85          ║
║       201645 ║ Compound   ║       205678 ║ Compound   ║ 0.35     ║ 205678 ║  764,799  ║  267,679.65          ║
║       206453 ║ Compound   ║       205678 ║ Compound   ║ 0.5      ║ 205678 ║  764,799  ║  382,399.50          ║
║       102847 ║ Isolated   ║       209876 ║ Compound   ║ 0.60     ║ 209876 ║  975,799  ║  585,479.40          ║
║       103844 ║ Isolated   ║       209876 ║ Compound   ║ 0.40     ║ 209876 ║  975,799  ║  390,319.60          ║
║       102847 ║ Isolated   ║       201645 ║ Compound   ║ 0.10     ║ 201645 ║  237,336  ║  23,733.60           ║
║       102346 ║ Isolated   ║       201645 ║ Compound   ║ 0.90     ║ 201645 ║  237,336  ║  213,602.40          ║
║       209846 ║ Compound   ║       206453 ║ Compound   ║ 0.38     ║ 206453 ║  825,702  ║  313,766.76          ║
║       102973 ║ Isolated   ║       206453 ║ Compound   ║ 0.12     ║ 206453 ║  825,702  ║  99,084.24           ║
║       109743 ║ Isolated   ║       206453 ║ Compound   ║ 0.50     ║ 206453 ║  825,702  ║  412,851.00          ║
║       103254 ║ Isolated   ║       209846 ║ Compound   ║ 1.00     ║ 209846 ║  332,103  ║  332,103.00          ║
╚══════════════╩════════════╩══════════════╩════════════╩══════════╩════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

The issue here is that I need to keep going (looping?) until the distribution is all on the Isolated Entities. Something like this:

```
╔════════╦══════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ Entity ║   Type   ║ Redistributed_Volume ║
╠════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ 103254 ║ Isolated ║  1,543,296.57        ║
║ 107892 ║ Isolated ║  403,352.95          ║
║ 102847 ║ Isolated ║  704,812.88          ║
║ 103844 ║ Isolated ║  436,207.54          ║
║ 102346 ║ Isolated ║  454,514.09          ║
║ 102973 ║ Isolated ║  144,972.18          ║
║ 109743 ║ Isolated ║  604,050.75          ║
║ 107427 ║ Isolated ║  500,386.05          ║
╚════════╩══════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

Finally, for validation purposes, we can take the sum of the Volume_Table (VT), Level_1_Distribution (LD1) and Redistributed_Volume (RV).

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║   VT    ║   LD1   ║   RV    ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ 4791593 ║ 4791593 ║ 4791593 ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: Your problem is complex. Is it a so-called "bill-of-materials" problem?

Comment: @O.Jones Kind of. I could do it manually and create "n" tables until there are not more Compound Entities in the distribution process. Then I just stacked all Isolated Entities rows of each previous n tables and sum up grouping by entity.